# Remove circle and path on click d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to remove a path and it the circles that are placed on it when a text label is clicked.

The line is removed on click but I am having trouble removing the circles too.

**The d3 code to remove the path is as follows.**

```
.on("click", function () {
            // Determine if current line is visible 
            var active = d.active ? false : true;
            var newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1; 
            // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
            d3.select("#line" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                .transition().duration(500) 
                .style("opacity", newOpacity); 
            // Update whether or not the elements are active
            d.active = active;
        })
```

**Please see the Plunker link for a better example for the whole code.**

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xk1y6VTOVNQFmUC6YBOi?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for, Made some changes and here is where the circles disappear
Thanks

`d3.selectAll(".dot"+d.key.replace(/\s+/,"")).transition().duration(500).style("opacity", newOpacity);`

Added Plunker Here [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uuzJf8XCd4i7Qg2RdFZp?p=preview)

Comment: Yes that will do. Do you know how I can make the circle/dot that is hovered over appear above any close circle/dots? (this happens on the last dots for the brown and red paths)

Comment: Yes , You need to create another circle and position it exactly over that DOT.
SVG doesnt have Z-Index and you cannot bring the lower layer on Top.